# Python Find Min Value In Array

Tags: python

Im trying to find the max/min values of the first column in an array short of importing anything

```
max = 0
min = 100000

for row in _file_in.readlines():
    Data = row.split(',') # Load first column
    if (Data[0] > max):
        max = Data[0]
    if (Data[0] < min):
        min = Data[0]
print min, max
```

I initialize max to 0 and min to some arbitrarily large number. My resulting code is able to print out the max # but the minimum # is printing out 100000 which is incorrect

Comment: Can you also include the content of your file?

Comment: `Data[0]` is a string. You should convert that to number. Perhaps use `int`

Comment: You really shouldn't use `min`, `max` as variable names as they clash with Python's builtins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your data is from a file and so you're comparing a string to a number.  In python2.x, the result from the comparison is only guaranteed to be consistent (the spec doesn't tell us what the result actually *is*).

You'll want to convert your strings to some sort of numeric type... e.g. `first_col = float(Data[0])` for the comparison.

```
for row in _file_in.readlines():
    Data = row.split(',') # Load first column
    first_col = float(Data[0])
    if (first_col > max):
        max = Data[0]
    if (first_col < min):
        min = Data[0]
    print min, max
```

---

Note, we can do a whole lot better using builtin functions and list-comprehensions:

```
first_col = [float(row.split(',')[0]) for row in _file_in]
print min(fist_col), max(first_col)
```

Notice that we didn't have to specify any artificial minima or maxima compared to your original solution, so this would work with input that consisted of entirely negative numbers (for example).

Comment: Great! Is there a way to remove the initialize of min to 10000? It seems like bad code to do this

Comment: @Bijan -- Turns out I was just typing that out :-)  Have a look.

Comment: @Bijan You can use `float('inf')` to initialize `min`, if you are not going to use the built-in `min` function.

Comment: Really should be `elif` to avoid the unnecessary comparison. `min`, `max` aren't ideal variable names.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, you could create a generator for your `first_col` and then just iterate over it. No need for any artificial initialisation of `mn` or `mx`. Is memory efficient and only iterates over the column once:

```
first_col = (int(row.split(',')[0]) for row in _file_in)
mn = mx = next(first_col, None)
for i in first_col:
    if i < mn:
        mn = i
    elif i > mx:
        mx = i
print mn, mx
```

For an empty file it will print `(None, None)`